# textviewcell label cover my background

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tableview, uitableview

hi i have a problem with a tableview. the cells textlabel ( default prototype cell ) hide part of my background. i don't understand why and how to change.

I know i could fix placing my own label, but i want to understand where's the mistake here.

**here is how it should be, with a line on the bottom... as a divider**

[image: here is how it should be, with a line on the bottom... as a divider]

**but here it is how it came out**

[image]

this is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    icons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             @"No Icon",
             @"Appointments",
             @"Birthdays",
             @"Chores",
             @"Drinks",
             @"Folder",
             @"Groceries",
             @"Inbox",
             @"Photos",
             @"Trips",
             nil];

    rowImage = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"row", @"row2", @"row3", @"row4", nil];

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [icons count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"IconCell"];
    NSString *icon = [icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rowImage objectAtIndex:arc4random()%4]]];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.textLabel.bounds = CGRectMake(cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.textLabel.frame.size.width, 10);
    cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.textLabel.frame.size.width, 10);
    cell.textLabel.text = icon;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:icon];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```